# MySQL do not accepts wildcard for tables name level grant

Tags: mysql, permissions, query, mysql-5.7

Trying to grant a user `select` privilege on multiple tables using wildcards as following:

```
GRANT SELECT ON 'DBname'.'foo_%' TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

But keep giving the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''DBname'.'foo_%' TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1
```

Server version: 5.7.30-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

I'm sure that the syntax of the query is correct, but for some reason it won't accept it, Any advise?

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887104/grant-privileges-on-several-tables-with-specific-prefix

Comment: I didn't see this before, but yes, it works! any idea why it didn't accept the raw query? is it a bug with that version and this workaround solve it?

Comment: that would be ahige security bug, which could cause many problems

Comment: How? can you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL 5.7 `GRANT` Syntax Documentation says something interesting about wildcards

Under the [subheading `Object Quoting Guidelines`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-quoting), Paragraph 1 says:

> Several objects within GRANT statements are subject to quoting, although quoting is optional in many cases: Account, database, table, column, and routine names. For example, if a user_name or host_name value in an account name is legal as an unquoted identifier, you need not quote it. However, quotation marks are necessary to specify a user_name string containing special characters (such as -), or a ***host_name string containing special characters or wildcard characters such as %*** (for example, 'test-user'@'%.com'). Quote the user name and host name separately.

Paragraphs 3 and 4 say

> ***The _ and % wildcards are permitted when specifying database names in GRANT statements that grant privileges at the database level*** (GRANT ... ON db_name.*). This means, for example, that to use a _ character as part of a database name, specify it as _ in the GRANT statement, to prevent the user from being able to ***access additional databases matching the wildcard pattern*** (for example, GRANT ... ON `foo\_bar`.* TO ...).
>
> ***When a database name not is used to grant privileges at the database level, but as a qualifier for granting privileges to some other object such as a table or routine (for example, GRANT ... ON db_name.tbl_name), wildcard characters are treated as normal characters***.

What about table privileges ? [Please note the Docs on `Table Privileges`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-table-privileges):

> Table privileges apply to all columns in a given table. To assign
> table-level privileges, use ON db_name.tbl_name syntax:
>
> ```
> GRANT ALL ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
> GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
> ```
>
> If you specify tbl_name rather than db_name.tbl_name, the statement
> applies to tbl_name in the default database. An error occurs if there
> is no default database.
>
> The permissible priv_type values at the table level are ALTER, CREATE
> VIEW, CREATE, DELETE, DROP, GRANT OPTION, INDEX, INSERT, REFERENCES,
> SELECT, SHOW VIEW, TRIGGER, and UPDATE.
>
> Table-level privileges apply to base tables and views. They do not
> apply to tables created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE, even if the table
> names match. For information about TEMPORARY table privileges, see
> Section 13.1.18.2, “CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Statement”.
>
> MySQL stores table privileges in the mysql.tables_priv system table.

As shown from the MySQL 5.7 `GRANTS` Documentation

- Wildcards are applicable to hostname (which are bold italiczied)
- Wildcards are applicable to database name (which are bold italiczied)
- Nowhere do the docs specify wildcards for table names
- Wildcard characters are treated as normal characters for all other database objects

The [workaround given in the comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/278420/mysql-do-not-accepts-wildcard-for-tables-name-level-grant#comment544005_278420) is what I used to do when giving away SELECT on views.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use skip special characters `\` in your command

```
GRANT SELECT ON 'DBname'.'foo\_%' TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```